# How to run an if statement against a shortcode attribute value in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, shortcode

I want to run an if statement on an attribute in my shortcode but for some reason it wont work?

I know that the attribute is being passed through because when I echo it were 'working' currently is I see the value so not sure what's wrong with my if statement?

```
if ( $atts['type'] == 'Platinum' ) {
?>
    <h2><?php echo 'working'?></h2>
<?php
} else {}
```

Comment: Where does the *$atts* array come from? can you add the declaration in the code?

Comment: It is defined earlier on in the code as the following - shortcode_atts(array( 'type' => '' ), $atts);

Comment: you can check value type by `vardump` for `$atts['type']` which will show correct value with spaces and data type. I also found that you are missing semicolon after `echo` inside `if` statement as well.

Comment: I vardumped it and got this string(21) "Platinum" so there isn't any spaces or anything hidden characters, I also tried adding semicolon but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shortcode attributes like below.

```
<?php
function function_name($atts) {
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'var1' => 'value1', //Assigning default value
    'var2' => 'value2',
  ), $atts));
  if($var1 == 'Platinum'){
    //Do things
  } else {
    //Do other things
  }
}//Function ends
add_shortcode('shortcode_name', 'function_name');
```

Comment: This works perfectly for my site. If you are having some problems, please share the code here.

Comment: Well, I think what breaks it is that the if statement is not in brackets, because when I add () to either side of the if the code runs but then I just get the same result as my code, any suggestions?

Comment: Edited the if brackets

Comment: No problems bro